# C++: How to call a parent class function from outside

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, virtual

I have:

```
class A{
    public:
        virtual void foo();
};

class B : public A{
    public:
        void foo();
};

B *ptr = new B();
```

I want to call A's `foo()` DIRECTLY using the 'ptr' pointer.

When I try

```
(A*)ptr->foo();
```

it still calls B's version of `foo()`. How do I call A's version instead?

Is this possible? What are the alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "didn't work"? What happens exactly when you try the above code?

Comment: Doing this completely defeats the purpose of making a function virtual, so it means that the user of class `A` is evading the class designer's intent. This probably means there is a design error somewhere: either `A` doesn't provide all the functionality that's needed, or the user of `A` doesn't understand what `A` is supposed to do.

Comment: @Code-Guru: Because the member function is virtual it will get dispatched to the final overrider regardless of the static type of the pointer (i.e. the cast is useless), unless you disable dynamic dispatch for the call...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas In the OP, the function wasn't even public and so the code shouldn't have even compiled and dispatching wouldn't yet be an issue. Thus why I asked what "doesn't work" means in this situation. I'm a little perturbed that I took the time to answer the wrong question because the OP was incomplete...

Comment: @Code-Guru- It calls B's foo() function.

Comment: @nahpr Thanks. I took the liberty to edit your question so that it more accurately reflects the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thank you. (at)Pete Becker - the A's foo() function needs to be virtual, just in this instance I need to call it directly. It's 'poly' after all.

Comment: @nahpr If you need to address comments to two different people, it helps to post two separate comments. Otherwise not all of the intended recipients will be notified of your comments.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you name a function with the `::` scope-resolution form, you call the named function, as though it were not virtual.

```
ptr->A::foo();
```

Comment: +1. That is correct, though it would be better if you also talk about the issue of accessibility in the OP's code.

Comment: @Nawaz: And even better if the fact that this breaks all OO principles was also mentioned :) The user of `B` should not care what version of `foo` is called, that is the main point of polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your functions public. You do this simply by making the following change:

```
class A{
    public:
        virtual void foo();
};

class B : public A{
    public:
        void foo();
};
```

When you don't do this, the functions are automatically private and inaccessible from the "outside".

Comment: They are public, I just didn't specify that in the example.

Comment: @nahpr For future reference, I suggest that you make a concientious effort to not introduce additional errors to the code that you post here. This will help avoid wasting your time sorting through unhelpful answers.